# Facebook like button not going back side on the fixed div

Tags: javascript, css, html, facebook-like

I added a Facebook like button to my website.My website has a fixed div on top of the page(blue color div in the image). The like button is below that(in a div which can scroll)
My problem is when the page is scroll down the like button comes on top of the fixed div(blue color).I want to scroll it from the backside of the div.How can I do that?
There are couple of screenshots I added

Before Scroll
[image: Before Scroll]

After Scroll
[image]

Here is my code of the fixed div

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function got_to_signup(){

    window.location.href = "view/policy";
    }

</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {

      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=368003049941951";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <div style="width:100%;background-color:#0094d6;"  >
    <div id="dd" style="background-color:#0094d6; width:100%; height:75px;position:fixed;  " class="center "><div id="a" style="width:1010px; height:75px; background-color:#000000;background:url(xx.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#003; " class="inner div_border">

      <table width="1010" border="0" >
        <tr >
          <td width="15%" rowspan="2"><a href="" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;"><div style="width:200px; height:50px;background-color:none;"></div></a></td>
          <td width="22%" height="14">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="28%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="23%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">


                </td>
          <td colspan="2"><span style="float: right; " ><div style="background-color:#006d9e;border-radius:3px; width:250px; height:34px; display: table;
    vertical-align: middle; color:#FFF; ">
            <table width="100%" border="0" >
              <tr >
                <td width="43%" style="text-align:center"> Start to bump !</td>
                <td width="29%"><div id='basic-modal'><span style="float: right; " ><input name="login_btn" type="button" class="login_button basic" id="login_btn" value="Sign in" /></span></div></td>
                <td width="28%"><span style="float: right; " ><form id="form_reg" method="post"><input name="register_btn" type="button" class="register_button" id="register_btn" value="Sign up" onclick="got_to_signup()"/></form></span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </div></span></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="color:#FFF; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; text-align:right;">    Beta Version   </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    </div></div></div>
```

here is my facebook like button code

```
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=368003049941951";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


              <td height="21" colspan="2"> <table width="187" style="margin-left:3px;font-size:1px;background-image:url(share_back.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;border-radius:3px;" >
          <!--tweeter button-->
          <tr><td width="71"><a href="https://twitter.com/bump_lk" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" style="float:right;">Follow @bump_lk</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></td>

    <!--facebook like button-->
          <td width="48"><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Bump.lk" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="10" data-show-faces="false" style="position:relative;"></div>
          </td></tr></table></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td >
```

Comment: Is there a difference of how you added the Twitter button as that one seems to be fine when looking at the screenshots?

Comment: tweeter button working fine.Its going backside when scroll.But facebook button is not like that :(

Comment: a z-index value on the fixed position div might help?

Comment: I tried Z index settin as z-index:1000; for the fixed div.But its not geting well

Comment: can you show the code that is adding the fb and twitter buttons as it is probably more of an issue with them oppose to the fixed header.

Comment: The problem is obviously how the javascript is inserting the fb button into the DOM. You have to look at the DOM in chrome to see if the javascript is creating the page the way you need to have it. Maybe `fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)` is not what you need after all. It's up to you to look at your DOM as it will be presented  in production, and tweak it. In this case the JS may be putting the _like_ `div` outside of `dd`, your fixed `div`, which is counter to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: endyourif: I added facebook like tweeter button code and the facebook like button code.

Comment: cube : how can I do it using DOM. I dont have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=368003049941951";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```